# How set counter and mode in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, counter

How do I set a counter with a loop?

```
@count=0

(w.submenu).each do |s|

    count=+1

      if(count == 4)

      else

      end

  count++

end
```

Comment: Note that Ruby doesn't support post-increment, so `count++` results in an error. Also, `count=+1` is a logic error as it's really doing `count = +1`, which assigns `1` to `count` so `count == 4` would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `each_with_index` method:

```
(w.submenu).each_with_index do |s, index|

      if(index == 4)
      else
      end
end
```

See the [Enumerable documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are using `@count=0` on the first line and `count` on the others.

Also I agree that `each_with_index` would be ideal.